# Dependency Issues in Ubuntu - I've Tried Everything

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, console

**So I recently installed Ubuntu 14.04 as my primary operating system. I have toyed with Ubuntu for years but have never had these kinds of issues to this degree at least. What's happening is that my laptop (64 bit) is running the 64 bit version of Ubuntu. This seems to be causing a lot of dependency issues and its a miracle when something installs all the way through. I have been looking through the interwebs on a solution to this but to no avail. I thought I'd at least see if any of you knew it. Below is the output I have been receiving when trying to install simple software packages. And I just installed Ubuntu today too!**

```
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 gnupg2 : Depends: gnupg-agent (= 2.0.22-3ubuntu1.3)
          Depends: libksba8 (>= 1.2.0) but it is not going to be installed
 gpa : Depends: gpgsm
 teamviewer:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.4) but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: libgcc1:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: libasound2:i386
                   Depends: libdbus-1-3:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: libexpat1:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: libfontconfig1:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: libfreetype6:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: libjpeg62:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: libpng12-0:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: libsm6:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: libxdamage1:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: libxext6:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: libxfixes3:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: libxinerama1:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: libxrandr2:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: libxrender1:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: libxtst6:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: zlib1g:i386 but it is not going to be installed
 webmin : Depends: libauthen-pam-perl but it is not going to be installed
          Depends: apt-show-versions but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Answer (score 2):

Just open software-properties-gtk by entering ALT with F2 and enter software-properties-gtk 
click on  Download from option
from drop down select other option
than click on Select Best Server
than it will take time locate best server
than select best server
hit OK
than it will show out of date pop up 
select reload option 
first it complete now your problem is resolved congratulations :)